# Puppeteer, distinguish between a redirect or a new html element (without timeouts)

Tags: javascript, promise, puppeteer

*TL;DR:* using puppeteer, after triggering a button click, which one is the best way to understand what is happening to a page, knowing that either a redirect / history push could happen (and the url change, in a set of known ones, but not necessarily through redirect but also through push into history object) or a dialog might appear (with a known id)?

---

I'm trying to write a scraper using Puppeteer (very first experience with it, never used before) to navigate a website with the final goal of retrieving a text code, with the challenge that the path to get there is not always the same, and the code might actually not be given.

In the first page - full of ads, therefore slow as well -, I do something like this to wait for the "get code" button to appear (snippet 1):

```js
// ... code to get the page instance ...

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

while(true) {
   // Puppeteer won't complain if I don't await for page reload (to avoid the ads),
   // as long as I await for the container div before doing anything else.
   page.reload(); // No await
   await page.waitForSelector("#code-container");
   const hasCode = await page.evaluate(() => {
      // I cannot click on it already because I realised it could 
      // cause a "Execution context was destroyed" error
      return document.querySelector('#get-code-button') != null;
   });
   if(!hasCode) {
      await sleep(10000);
   }
}

// out of the loop, "#get-code-button" exists
```

And then I click on it (snippet 2):

```js
// For some reason, this method is more reliable than using 
// await page.click('#get-code-button').
await page.evaluate(async () => { 
   document.querySelector('#get-code-button').click()
});

// ... at this point the real troubles begin ...
```

Now, after the snippet above, a few scenarios might happen:

1. A dialog might appear, with the "reveal code" button in it (happy days)
2. A redirect might happen (url change, but it could be either a redirect either a push in the history object), with ads. After clicking on the div with id "continue-without-ads" (to simplify), I end up in one of the next redirects.
3. A redirect might happen (as above, url change, but it could be either a redirect either a push in the history object), with the "reveal code" button in it (happy days)
4. A redirect might happen (same as above), with basically written "error: code not available". If I go back from this page, the "get code" button should stay in place, so I could skip snippet 1 and go straight for snippet 2.

Question is, how can I detect in which scenario am I, and act timely (e.g. without waiting for the waitForSelector timeout to happen if I want to check for element to be there)?

As well, is the idea of using *page.goBack()* to get to the initial link and make another attempt a stupid one (to avoid waiting for the "get-code-button" to appear again, since the page should now be cached in Chrome)?

I want to avoid the headache of myself mashing the refresh button, clicking the "get-code-button" once it appears and go back to retry until I get the code.

Answer (score 0):

I found an escamotage, but I don't think it's the easiest way to achieve what I wanted, neither the most correct ...

My solution is to have two "aggregators" of waiters: (1) one for selectors (a list of IDs, but any selector is just fine), (2) one for page url changes (a list of urls which are gonna trigger the promise if navigated to). Both this aggregators accepts as input a list of string (in one case selectors, in the other urls), and returns the first one to succeed.

The code to check what changed in the page after the click:

```js
/**
 * @param page the page to monitor for changes
 * @param urls the list of urls that should trigger the redirect monitor
 * @param selectors the list of selectors that should trigger the page change
 * @param triggerPromise the promise that triggers the events (e.g. mouse click on a button)
 * @returns the url or the selector that resulted as a change
 */
async function waitForWinner(page: Page, urls: string[], selectors: string[], triggerPromise: Promise<any>) {

  // waitForUrlChange takes in input a list of urls, and returns the first
  // one to succeed
  const urlChangeMonitor = waitForUrlChange(page, urls);

  // hasSelectors takes in input the list of selectors, and returns
  // the first that succeeds 
  const selectorsPromise = hasSelectors(page, selectors);

  const results = await Promise.all([
    triggerPromise,
    Promise.race([ urlChangeMonitor.promise, selectorsPromise ])
  ]);

  urlChangeMonitor.clear();

  const winner = results[1];
  // This check is quite stupid, but it works for me:
  const isRedirect = !winner.startsWith("#");
  const isSelector =  winner.startsWith("#");

  // ... other custom logic here

  // Simplification:
  return { winner, isRedirect, isSelector }

}
```

The `hasSelectors` is a bit trivial, and it's full of custom logic in my case (when there are cookies it accepts them and then keeps going again), the most interesting part is the one to wait for url change.

In my case I realised there is no redirect, thus I suppose it's a push in the history object. Regardless, this method succeeds in listening for url changes in the page:

```js
const unboundResolve = (url: string) => logger.error("Resolved too early, error.");
const unboundReject  = ()            => logger.error("Rejected too early, error.");

export function waitForUrlChange(page: Page, urls: string[], timeout=60000) {

  if (urls.length === 0) {
    throw Error("Cannot have 0 lenght array of urls.");
  }

  const deferred = {
    resolve: unboundResolve,
    reject:  unboundReject
  };

  const promise: Promise<string> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred.resolve = resolve;
    deferred.reject  = reject;
  });

  let promiseDone = false;

  const checkForUrl = (frame: Frame) => {

    const isRoot = frame.parentFrame() === null;

    if (isRoot) {

      // Frame might change, but page doesn't always change.
      // Regardless, in this way I can detect url changes which 
      // occurs without redirect.
      const currentUrl = page.url(); 

      for(let u of urls) {
        if (~currentUrl.indexOf(u)) {
          // Resolve only once
          if(!promiseDone) {
            promiseDone = true;
            deferred.resolve(currentUrl);
          } else {
            logger.warn(`Found another redirect of interest, but it's too late now.`);
          }
          clear();
          break;
        }
      }

    }

  };

  const clear = () => {
    if (!promiseDone) {
      deferred.reject();
      promiseDone = true;
    }
    // Calling it multiple times doesn't make a difference
    page.off("framenavigated", checkForUrl);
  }

  // If url doesn't change in one minute, call it a day
  setTimeout(clear, timeout);

  page.on("framenavigated", checkForUrl);

  // Provide a way to turn off the listener from outside
  return { clear, promise };

}
```

Main idea is to register to *framenavigated* event and listen for the url to contain one of the inputs (not the best, but works for me). Rather than directly returning a promise, I wrap it into an object which gives the possibility to clear the listener from outside, to keep things tidy.

The approach I presented has vast room for improvement (e.g. rather than having strings being passed around, I could add metadata and then the metadata is returned as well, to avoid very naive checks like *.startsWith("#")*, or the check for url could be a pattern or a callback), but it works and shows the main idea behind.